# How to create scoped selects of the same has_many through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I am working on a product admin section. I have `productvariants`, which can have many `productattributevalues` through `productvariantdetails`.

`productattributevalues` (green, yellow, S, XL) belongs_to `productattributes` (color, size and material).

I would like to have two separate selectors on my `productvariants/_form` where I can choose (optionally) if a `productvariant` has an `productattributevalue` of the `productattribute`kind of: size or color applied.

I changed my models and introduced two aliases for `productattributevalues`. One for each attribute.

```
class Productvariant < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :productattributesizes, :productattributecolors

  has_many :productattributevalues
  has_many :productvariantdetails
  has_many :productattributevalues, :through => :productvariantdetails
  has_many :productattributecolors, :through => :productvariantdetails, :source => :productattributevalue
  has_many :productattributesizes, :through => :productvariantdetails, :source => :productattributevalue
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :productvariantdetails, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Productattributevalue < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :value, :productattribute_id
  scope :product_color, joins(:productattribute).where('productattributes.attributename' => 'color')
  scope :product_size, joins(:productattribute).where('productattributes.attributename' => 'size')

  belongs_to :productattribute
end
```

This is my view

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @productvariant], :html => {'role' => 'form' } do |f| %>
    .
    .
    .
  <%= f.select(:productattributecolors, Productattributevalue.product_color.uniq.order('id asc').map{|s| [s.value, s.id]}, {:selected => params[:productattributecolor], :include_blank => false, :prompt => "Select color"}, {}) %>
  <%= f.select(:productattributesizes, Productattributevalue.product_size.uniq.order('id asc').map{|s| [s.value, s.id]}, {:selected => params[:productattributesize], :include_blank => false, :prompt => "Select size"}, {}) %>
    .
    .
    .
    <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

I currently get:

```
Productattributevalue(#2232715140) expected, got String(#70262645253120)
```

How can I get this working?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set `productattributecolor_ids` and `productattributesize_ids` in the view:

```
<%= f.select(:productattributecolor_ids, Productattributevalue.product_color.uniq.order('id asc').map{|s| [s.value, s.id]}, {:include_blank => false, :prompt => "Select color"}, {}) %>
<%= f.select(:productattributesize_ids, Productattributevalue.product_size.uniq.order('id asc').map{|s| [s.value, s.id]}, {:include_blank => false, :prompt => "Select size"}, {}) %>
```

as well as add both to the `attr_accessible` of the `productvatriant.rb` model:

```
class Productvariant < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :productattributesize_ids, :productattributecolor_ids
  .
  .
  .
end
```

This way I can choose to set attribute values for both attributes or let them blank.